# Sql Server Replication issue (Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Getting below error message in synchronization history during synchronizing of subscription

Error messages:
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 8114)
Get help: http://help/8114

For finding the exact issue, we have checked windows sql server event log and found something below:

```
System

  - Provider

   [ Name]  MSSQL$VERB1

  - EventID 14151

   [ Qualifiers]  49152

   Level 2

   Task 2

   Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

   [ SystemTime]  2016-05-06T06:14:28.000000000Z

   EventRecordID 554838

   Channel Application

   Computer xxx-01

  - Security

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-21-2320706869-2720452709-2089460225-500


- EventData

 Replication Merge Subsystem
 xxxxDB-yyyyDB
 Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
 4737000012000000100000004C004F004E002D0044004200
 2D00300031005C004E00450052005600380000000D
 000000640069007300740072006900620075007400
 69006F006E000000


Binary data:


In Words

0000: 00003747 00000012 00000010 004F004C
0010: 002D004E 00420044 0030002D 005C0031
0020: 0045004E 00560052 00000038 0000000D
0030: 00690064 00740073 00690072 00750062
0040: 00690074 006E006F 0000  


In Bytes

0000: 47 37 00 00 12 00 00 00   G7......
0008: 10 00 00 00 4C 00 4F 00   ....X.X.
0010: 4E 00 2D 00 44 00 42 00   X.-.D.B.
0018: 2D 00 30 00 31 00 5C 00   -.0.1.\.
0020: 4E 00 45 00 52 00 56 00   V.E.R.B.
0028: 38 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00   1.......
0030: 64 00 69 00 73 00 74 00   d.i.s.t.
0038: 72 00 69 00 62 00 75 00   r.i.b.u.
0040: 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00   t.i.o.n.
0048: 00 00                     ..
```

Also we increased output verbose level higher (-OutputVerboseLevel 2) 
 but we did not get anything in log.

we are using 
**Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3)  (X64)**

we are now unable to understand this sql server event log so please 
help me out if you have any suggestion

Thanks & Regards,
Rama

Comment: Well - the error message tells you that there's data you're trying to convert to numeric which isn't numeric. You need to either fix your data or change your synchronization.